# How to delete a registered user by using firebase auth in android studio?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created the Register method using firebase authentication user register method.

How to delete a registered user by using firebase auth and android studio?

```
private void registerUser(){
            String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();


firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>(){

                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        //user successfully registered and logged in
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registered Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProfileActivity.class));

                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Could Not Register. Please Try Again Later",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });

}
private void deleteUser(){

  // TODO: Fill this method

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `delete()` method to remove the desired user from the Firebase. Please use this code:

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
AuthCredential authCredential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential("user@example.com", "password1234");

firebaseUser.reauthenticate(authCredential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        firebaseUser.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User account deleted!");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks that was helpful. can u tell me according to that userId how can i delete data from database

Comment: This question is not related with the first one. So in order to answer it,  please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: when i used that method user get deleted but the application Unfortunately get stops and restart.

Comment: Just post another fresh question, and please don't forget  to mention the error you get.