# Firebase Authentication Android : Delete Any Authenticated User

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created one application, in that I am managing three levels of users like **"Admin"**, **"Sub Admin"** and **"Customers"**

Now I am adding Functionality of "Delete Sub Admin" that I want to remove from Authentication of Firebase.

I found some answers but that is for **currentUser** only.

I show [deleteUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user) method in docs but I think its removed or deprecated.

Any other solution replaced for this method? Any clue?

Your help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409048/how-to-delete-firebase-authentication-users-from-android-app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44631947/how-to-delete-a-registered-user-by-using-firebase-auth-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to delete an authenticated user:

```java
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential("email", "password");

user.reauthenticate(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        user.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

   }
});
```

The above code first checks if a user is authenticated or not by re-authenticating, and it deletes the user if the task is successful.